# is there library rether than HtmlUnit that support javascript

Tags: java, web-crawler, webclient

hello i am using htmlunit for the first time
and i have the following error .

> TypeError: Cannot find function enableSuggest in object [object Object]. (script in http://mysite.aspx from (854, 32) to (859, 10)#857)]
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot find function enableSuggest in object [object Object]. (script in http:

is it not supporting the script in my site ?if yes what solution or library is to be use

Comment: HtmlUnit has poor support for JavaScript. It does not support wordpress-based sites (f.g. blog.com). It fails when anything goes wrong. It's behaviour is far from what would be expected from browser.

Answer (score 1):

HtmlUnit supports a "standard" set of javascript objects and functions, but it's pretty easy to trip it up and throw it something it can't handle. Sounds like you have one of those.

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i am trying to read a web page that have single URL and many pages using java script .Do you have any idea to get all the cotain of the page

Answer (score 0):

http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/ supports JavaScript however as far as I can tell from my experience the support is far from perfect.

Comment: ok do you have any suggest how can i read content of web page contain many pages using Java script with the same URL

Comment: You may want to rephrase the question, so that we can clearly understand what you're trying to do. So far I have no idea!